# Why can macos(x86) run docker arm container arm64v8/alpine?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, emulation, qemu

I happened to find that my macos(x86) can run a docker container for an arm image arm64v8/alpine, but with the following warning:

```
docker run -it  arm64v8/alpine uname -a

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
Linux d5509c57dd24 4.19.121-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Dec 1 17:50:32 UTC 2020 aarch64 Linux
```

And I'm pretty sure the image is not a multi-arch image (`docker manifest inspect --verbose arm64v8/alpine`). Why can x86 run an arm container?

Comment: I may be off but I believe this is related to the fact that qemu is bundled to run [arm images](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/) also mentioned in [this post](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/). Although this might be negated by your inspect command. This is also used to run amd64 images on Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are correct, the image is not multi architecture, yet, docker can run it. Reason behind this is a kernel subsystem called `binfmt_misc` which allows to set the `magic` numbers of a binary file to specific actions for their execution. You can read more in this nice [wikipedia post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) about it.

Docker for Mac is arriving prepared for the `binfmt` magic, so there is nothing to be done to enable it. It will be enabled out-of-box with the installation, all you need to do is to fetch the image and run. The details of the mechanism can be found in repository of docker-for-mac project on this [link](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/2d8b420d3c49712ec4a7bcec1464278fa4c41936/docker-for-mac/multi-arch.md).

To explain it simply, the binary images have the `magic` number that allows the kernel to decide how to handle the execution. When `binfmt_misc` intercepts a file for which it recognizes the `magic` numbers it will invoke the handler that is associated with the `magic` numbers.

This alone is not enough to run the container. The next part of the *magic* is `QEMU` which is the emulator for various CPU architectures. The kernel (`binfmt_misc`) will invoke the quemy for each of the binaries that are ARM64 and will emulate the ARM64v8.

This is not limited to `docker` nor to the virtual machine that is running the `docker` on `macOS`. Any linux system can be configured to do this.

You can use following to install it setup Ubuntu to run the emulation.

```
sudo apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static # Install the qemu packages
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes # This step will execute the registering scripts

docker run --rm -t arm64v8/ubuntu uname -m # Testing the emulation environment
```

More details about the whole process of the set-up can be found in the [qemu-user-static](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static) repository

> OP: If you are wondering what is the usefulness of this, from my personal experiance, I am using this functionality heavily when porting applications from X86 to other architectures (mainly ARM64). This allows me to run build systems for various architectures without having a physical machine on which I can run the build.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 

But I can't remember that I installed qemu on my macos Big Sur 11.2.1. 
I checked with brew list and pkgutil --pkgs. Is there any other way to confirm that qemu is installed on my machine ?

Comment: On macOS you don't need to install anything, the docker is shipped ready for `bitfmt` magic. This is part of the `Docker for Mac` itself.

Comment: Yeah, on MacOS this runs out of the box. But on Ubuntu arm64 host building a docker container using --platform arm64 I needed to install:
`sudo apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static # Install the qemu packages`